# :hover on span in button not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

CSS not working for span tag hover, which is inside button tag in Internet Explorer, I have button that if you hover on it it will display the tooltip and I want if you hover the tooltip it should disappear, it is working in FF and chrome but not IE,I knew that I should use

> .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext

instead of

> .tooltiptext:hover

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}

.tooltiptext:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">

<div class="tooltip">
  <button type="button">Hover me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what are suggestions, I'm open to use jquery too. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of IE is causing problems?

Comment: I'm testing by IE 11

Answer (score 1):

to my knowledge what you are doing is wrong:

the "tooltiptext" is a child element of the "tooltip"...

..so when you are hovering the "tooltiptext" you also are hovering the "tooltip".
In fact it's also not working on Chrome. it just flickers.

You should just show the "tooltiptext" when you hover the "tooltip" an hide it when you move away from it.

by removing this:

```
/*
.tooltiptext:hover {
    display: none;
}
*/
```

Or even easier use the title property:

```
<button type="button" title="Tooltip text">Hover me</button>
```

Comment: I don't want to use title for some reason, and if you have multiple button next to each other then if you hover then tooltip will appear on top of other button then user have to move the far from the buttons, hope you understand what I need to approach. but you are right about chrome and FF, it's just flickers but it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, took me a bit to get used to how jQuery works in JSFiddle, but if you're willing to use jQuery then this *should* work.

```js
$('.tooltip').mouseover(function() {
  $('.tooltiptext').css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('.tooltip').mouseout(function() {
  $('.tooltiptext').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
} */


/* .tooltiptext:hover {
    display: none;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="text-align:center;">

  <div class="tooltip">
    <button type="button">Hover me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note that I've commented out the portion of the CSS to adjust the tooltiptext visibility. With this method you can safely remove it. Also note that my jQuery implementation is a bit messy as I neglected to put the hover effects inside a function. This snippet just tries to show the answer. Good luck.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question, your code not working, I need if you hover the tooltip(I mean "tooltiptext" class then make it disappear) not the button, $('.tooltip').mouseout action is on button. otherwise my code worked before, hover the button and then hover the tooltip, it should be hidden, in IE it's not working.